# What's the source that there is תשלומין for tefilla?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilla

What's the source that there is תשלומין for tefilla? Is it learnt out from תשלומין of korbanos?

Also related to this: do the daily karbanos, such as the tamid, have תשלומין if they weren’t brought at their proper time? Or is תשלומין only for the karbanos of the shalosh regalim?

Comment: Berachos 26a https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.26a.17?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en

Comment: Isn't it rabbinic? What kind of source derivation are you looking for? The rabbis can enact any sort of prayer service without prior precedent.

Comment: @DoubleAA they can but tefilla was enacted כנגד קרבנות according to some so it’s possible that tashlumin of tefilla is also learnt from there. I’m looking for a source that says so explicitly.